# How to migrate data from oracle db to mysql db?

Tags: mysql, oracle, migration, mysql-workbench

I have an Oracle database and I want to migrate data to a Mysql database since I'm trying to configure an application to work with Mysql.

I tried this using Mysql Workbench Migration Wizard, but I am unable to connect to the Oracle database.

I got this error:

> "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver an Application"

And I also got http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66609 link and it says that Workbench doesn't support Oracle.

Are there any other free tools to migrate data from Oracle to Mysql ?

Or any other alternatives to get this done?

Comment: I have used SQlyog for this. But it is a paid version.But any way you can download trail and check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701377/mysql-connect-import-a-tabele-of-oracle-database

Answer (score 0):

Export to excel and import it with SQL Navicat Premium mysql

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench has a dedicated migration module, supporting various source RDBMS (provided they have a JDBC driver) as well as MySQL to MySQL transitions (e.g. for upgrading or migrating a MySQL server to a new machine).

MySQL Workbench is free. For more informations, downloads, blogs etc see http://mysqlworkbench.org

Comment: MySQL Workbench doesn't support Oracle to MySQL though, and any attempts to use the tool for Oracle to MySQL will not work.

Answer (score 0):

With [FoxWeave](http://www.foxweave.com/apps-and-dbs/sync-oracle-new-records-to-mysql-new-records/), an integration tool, you can also migrate data from oracle db to mysql db.